# ObjectlistView Checkbox Issue

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox, checkboxlist, objectlistview

I have an issue trying to get a Checkbox working with `ObjectListview`.

My model looks like this:

```
public class object
{   
    public string name {get; set;}
    public int age {get; set;}
    public bool inuse {get; set;}
}
```

And I added a `FastObjectListView` via the Designer in Visual Studio to a Win Forms Application. 
Then, I added the Columns and set the `AspectName` for each column to the Models Property (First column: AspectName: name, Second Column: AspectName: age, Third Column: AspectName: inuse).

Afterwards, I filled the `ListView` with this:

```
using (var context = new objectDb())
{
    var objectlist = context.objects.ToList();
    fastoLV_Clean.SetObjects(objectlist);                             
    fastoLV_Clean.Refresh();
}
```

That works, and I can see my Database entries in the `ListView`.

Now I want to add a CheckBox column where someone can check or uncheck the items to delete them and I can not get the checkbox to work.

I have added a Column and set `CheckBox` to true, changed the `CheckedAspectName` of the `ListView` and now I can see the Checkboxes but nothing happens if I click them to check. 
I think I'm on the completely wrong track, what do I have to do to make it work?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know a way with the ObjectListView to include any items which are not part of your model.

So then the simple way is to change your model to include a "Delete" property which you can then show in your ObjectListView.

Of course, this is not always possible!  Especially if you are dealing with items that are written to/from Database or another persistence layer.

Then the trick is to write a derived class with you model being the base class and then you just add the delete column to this.  But then you would need to convert from your Base to a derived class before showing in the ObjectListView.

The following code can help with that.

You keep your columns set-up as you have already done.
Assuming your (now base) class is defined like this

```
 public class MyClass
 {   
     public string name { get; set; }
     public int age { get; set; }
     public bool inuse { get; set; }
 }
```

Your derived class inherits from this, adds the delete property and a new constructor

```
public class MySecondClass : MyClass
{
    public bool Delete { get; set; }

    public MySecondClass(MyClass other)
    {
        //Copy from MyClass
        this.name = other.name;
        this.age = other.age;
        this.inuse = other.inuse;

        //Set default for new properties
        this.Delete = false;
    }
}
```

Your code to retrieve the objects and set them then looks like this

```
using (var context = new objectDb())
{
    var objectlist = context.objects.ToList();

    //Now we need to convert to the derived class type
     var secondlist = list.ConvertAll(x => new MySecondClass(x));

     //Then we setobjects using this new list
     fastoLV_Clean.SetObjects(secondlist);     
}
```